# Proof $S$ is the intersection of $m$ subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-r$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $k$-space with $dim(V)=n$.

Let $S\subset V$ be a subspace, $\dim\left(S\right)=k<n $. For each $r\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq r\leq n-k$, prove that $S$ is the intersection of $m$  subspaces of $V$ of dimension $n-r$.

I need help, I don't know how to start.

Comment: That can't be, since the inequalities also hold for all $n'\gt n$. Perhaps you forgot to state $n=\dim V$?

Comment: What?? @joriki .

Comment: It would be more helpful if you pointed out which part of what I wrote wasn't clear. Other than in the claim, $n$ currently appears only in two inequalities. If these inequalities hold for $n$, they also hold for any $n'\gt n$. Thus, if you could prove the claim for $n$, you could also prove it for any $n'\gt n$. That can't be, since if $V$ is finite-dimensional there aren't subspaces of $V$ of arbitrarily large dimension $n'-r$. Thus there must be something wrong with the claim in its current form. My suggestion was that what's wrong might be that you forgot to state $n=\dim V$.

Comment: ahhh, yes!!!! of course, sorry. @joriki